# 2 IP cameras with same configuration but different behaviour

Tags: networking, wifi, ip, p2p

I have a Vodafone Station router, and 2 IP cameras connected to it through an Ethernet cable. 
Both have the same configuration. Both DHCP enabled, one has IP 192.168.1.10 with port 81  and the other 192.168.1.8 with port 3333.

While I am connected to the Wi-Fi, they are both accessible and work fine, both from the IP camera Android application and from the Browser (using the ADDRESS IPaddress:port), but when I try to access externally from the Android application using my 3G mobile operator network, the second IP camera does not work... it says "ID not valid".

I have tried every possible permutation of configurations to my knowledge, also disabling the DHCP and assigning a static IP address through port forwarding, but it simply does not work, even though the second camera has an identical configuration as the first one. 
But now I finished my ideas!

What could I possibly do wrong?

Comment: This is a question for vendor support. It is also possible that you have a simple networking issue. Either way, this seems off-topic here.

Comment: You should configure port forwarding for both cameras separately, once for 192.168.1.10 port 81, and once for 192.168.1.8 port 3333.

Comment: What do you mean separately? I've tried assigning the two IP addresses/ports but it didn't work out.